# building a graph from boolean expression in c++

Tags: c++, graph, boolean

I am trying convert `(A+(B*C))` into a graph structure where `+` represents parallel connection and `*` represents series connection. if `n1`, `n2`, and `n3` are the three nodes in the graph then:

`n1` has `edge(A),edge(B)`.

`n2` has `edge(B),edge(C)`.

`n3` has `edge(A),edge(C)`.

I know that the variables in boolean expression will be edges but i can't understand how 
to find the nodes from the expression given for the vertices of graph.

Comment: Look at that as a parsing problem. And show the code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [expression templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates) to generate the syntax tree of the expression:

```
class Boolean
{
public:
    Boolean(bool b) : _b( b ) {}

private:
    bool _b;
};

template<typename LHS , typename RHS>
struct parallel
{
    LHS& left;
    RHS& right;  

    parallel(const LHS& _left , const RHS& _right) : left( _left ) , right( _right ) {}
};

template<typename LHS , typename RHS>
struct serie
{
    LHS& first;
    RHS& second;  

    serie(const LHS& _left , const RHS& _right) : first( _left ) , second( _right ) {}
};


/* Boolean vs Boolean parallel expression */
parallel<Boolean,Boolean> operator+(const Boolean& lhs , const Boolean& rhs)
{
    return parallel<Boolean,Boolean>( lhs , rhs );
}

/* Boolean vs Boolean serie expression */
serie<Boolean,Boolean> operator*(const Boolean& lhs , const Boolean& rhs)
{
    return serie<Boolean,Boolean>( lhs , rhs );
}


/* Boolean vs internal node parallel expressions */

template<typename LHS , typename RHS>
parallel<parallel<LHS,RHS>,Boolean> operator+(const parallel<LHS,RHS>& lhs , const Boolean& rhs)
{
    return parallel<parallel<LHS,RHS>,Boolean>( lhs , rhs );
}

template<typename LHS , typename RHS>
parallel<Boolean,parallel<LHS,RHS>> operator+(const Boolean& lhs , const parallel<LHS,RHS>& rhs)
{
    return parallel<Boolean,parallel<LHS,RHS>>( lhs , rhs );
}

template<typename LHS , typename RHS>
parallel<serie<LHS,RHS>,Boolean> operator+(const serie<LHS,RHS>& lhs , const Boolean& rhs)
{
    return parallel<serie<LHS,RHS>,Boolean>( lhs , rhs );
}

template<typename LHS , typename RHS>
parallel<Boolean,serie<LHS,RHS>> operator+(const Boolean& lhs , const serie<LHS,RHS>& rhs)
{
    return parallel<Boolean,serie<LHS,RHS>>( lhs , rhs );
}


/* Boolean vs internal node serie expresssions */

template<typename LHS , typename RHS>
serie<parallel<LHS,RHS>,Boolean> operator*(const parallel<LHS,RHS>& lhs , const Boolean& rhs)
{
    return serie<parallel<LHS,RHS>,Boolean>( lhs , rhs );
}

template<typename LHS , typename RHS>
serie<Boolean,parallel<LHS,RHS>> operator*(const Boolean& lhs , const parallel<LHS,RHS>& rhs)
{
    return serie<Boolean,parallel<LHS,RHS>>( lhs , rhs );
}

template<typename LHS , typename RHS>
serie<serie<LHS,RHS>,Boolean> operator*(const serie<LHS,RHS>& lhs , const Boolean& rhs)
{
    return serie<serie<LHS,RHS>,Boolean>( lhs , rhs );
}

template<typename LHS , typename RHS>
serie<Boolean,serie<LHS,RHS>> operator*(const Boolean& lhs , const serie<LHS,RHS>& rhs)
{
    return serie<Boolean,serie<LHS,RHS>>( lhs , rhs );
}


/* internal node vs internal node parallel expressions */

template<typename LHS1 , typename RHS1 , typename LHS2 , typename RHS2>
parallel<parallel<LHS1,RHS1>,parallel<LHS2,RHS2>> operator+(const parallel<LHS1,RHS1>& lhs , const parallel<LHS2,RHS2>& rhs)
{
    return parallel<parallel<LHS1,RHS1>,parallel<LHS2,RHS2>>( lhs , rhs );
}

template<typename LHS1 , typename RHS1 , typename LHS2 , typename RHS2>
parallel<serie<LHS1,RHS1>,serie<LHS2,RHS2>> operator+(const serie<LHS1,RHS1>& lhs , const serie<LHS2,RHS2>& rhs)
{
    return parallel<serie<LHS1,RHS1>,serie<LHS2,RHS2>>( lhs , rhs );
}

template<typename LHS1 , typename RHS1 , typename LHS2 , typename RHS2>
parallel<parallel<LHS1,RHS1>,serie<LHS2,RHS2>> operator+(const parallel<LHS1,RHS1>& lhs , const serie<LHS2,RHS2>& rhs)
{
    return parallel<parallel<LHS1,RHS1>,serie<LHS2,RHS2>>( lhs , rhs );
}

template<typename LHS1 , typename RHS1 , typename LHS2 , typename RHS2>
parallel<serie<LHS1,RHS1>,parallel<LHS2,RHS2>> operator+(const serie<LHS1,RHS1>& lhs , const parallel<LHS2,RHS2>& rhs)
{
    return parallel<serie<LHS1,RHS1>,parallel<LHS2,RHS2>>( lhs , rhs );
}


/* internal node vs internal node serie expressions */

template<typename LHS1 , typename RHS1 , typename LHS2 , typename RHS2>
serie<parallel<LHS1,RHS1>,parallel<LHS2,RHS2>> operator*(const parallel<LHS1,RHS1>& lhs , const parallel<LHS2,RHS2>& rhs)
{
    return serie<parallel<LHS1,RHS1>,parallel<LHS2,RHS2>>( lhs , rhs );
}

template<typename LHS1 , typename RHS1 , typename LHS2 , typename RHS2>
serie<serie<LHS1,RHS1>,serie<LHS2,RHS2>> operator*(const serie<LHS1,RHS1>& lhs , const serie<LHS2,RHS2>& rhs)
{
    return serie<serie<LHS1,RHS1>,serie<LHS2,RHS2>>( lhs , rhs );
}

template<typename LHS1 , typename RHS1 , typename LHS2 , typename RHS2>
serie<parallel<LHS1,RHS1>,serie<LHS2,RHS2>> operator*(const parallel<LHS1,RHS1>& lhs , const serie<LHS2,RHS2>& rhs)
{
    return serie<parallel<LHS1,RHS1>,serie<LHS2,RHS2>>( lhs , rhs );
}

template<typename LHS1 , typename RHS1 , typename LHS2 , typename RHS2>
serie<serie<LHS1,RHS1>,parallel<LHS2,RHS2>> operator*(const serie<LHS1,RHS1>& lhs , const parallel<LHS2,RHS2>& rhs)
{
    return serie<serie<LHS1,RHS1>,parallel<LHS2,RHS2>>( lhs , rhs );
}
```

An example of its usage could be:

```
int main()
{
    Boolean a(true) , b(false) , c(true);
    auto result = (a+b)*(a+c); //serie(parallel(a,b),parallel(a,c))
}
```